# Do I need all of the Android SDK Build-Tools?

Tags: android, build-tools, android-sdk-manager

I have everything working fine, but just confused with Android SDK Build-Tools.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          There are so many versions in the SDK manager, do I need all the revisions of the Android SDK Build-Tools? or just the latest one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest one includes and supports the older ones.

Comment: thanks bob, can you tell me what to download in an Android version  out of these? (in SDK manager ofcourse) 1. Documentation for android SDK 2. SDK platform 3. ARM images 4. Intel images 5. Google APis 6. sources for android SDK.

Comment: i just need a virtual device for that android version (lollipop), i think i just need 2, and 3.

Comment: Since I work with Bluetooth and the virtual devices don't support Bluetooth I dont download any of the images. Since they are huge that saves lots of space. But I would rather the emulators support Bluetooth!