# Do I need all of the Android SDKs and how should I install them?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When targeting a Xamarin.Forms App (PCL) from a certain Android version and up - does that mean that I need the SDKs for all of the levels from that version up, or is it enough to have the highest level and it will include the rest? E.g. If I'm targeting 6.0 and up, is it enough to have SDK 26, or do I need also 23, 24, and 25?
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386950/939213)  one is enough. but according to [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/install-android-sdk-packages/)  I need all of them.

And if I do need to install all of them, should this be done from Visual Studio installer, or from the Android SDK Manager inside Visual Studio? Is there a difference between them? (I'm using VS2017 latest version 15.5.2)

Comment: This advice on the documentation is wrong. You only need the versions set for your `compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and minSdkVersion`. In total you might have 3 different installed SDK Platforms.

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks. This means that the answer (currently the only one) to this question (saying I only need one) is incorrect as well. Correct?

Comment: No it's not wrong because you only need one level to "compile against" which is correct as it's backwards compatible (additive of apis). I added that note of you *might* use three for testing purposes such as emulator images. You only need one SDK Platform (latest) in majority of cases. You would then have the respective System Images from other API levels for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the one you're targeting, with the targetSDK parameter of your manifest.  Note that target and minimum are different things-  its the target you need.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why, then, does Xamarin say otherwise? `Install the "SDK Platform" for the Android versions you've set as minimum, target, and in-between the minimum & target. ` (and on) in the link in my question.

Comment: And should I install it from VS installer or from the Android SDK Manager?