# how do I install a specific android sdk build tools version and how do I use 2 of them? on Mac

Tags: android, build-tools

I want to start an App using the Terminal via command: "tns run android" 
I always get the following error:

"You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=25'."

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386699/do-i-need-all-of-the-android-sdk-build-tools) that every version includes and supports any older version which obviously can't be true. 
I tried downloading it and copied it in the folder where I think it needs to be (/users/admin/library/android/sdk/build-tools). Do I have to change/do anything else?
On top of that I need Android sdk-tools 27.0.1 (which Im pretty sure is installed (otherwise it couldn't build the project I guess)) or higher for Android studios and I don't know if I can even solve this problem because of that. I heard that you can run 2 build-tool versions at once but I don't know how.
Please help I never worked with this before and am absolutely clueless.

If you need to know anything else ask me in the comments and I will give you the required information.